# Real Signal Properties and $\cos(t)$ Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing

I am struggling to conceptually understand why the Fourier coefficients for $\cos(t)$ are $a_1 = 1/2$ and $a_{-1} = 1/2$ in light of the fact that, for a real and even signal, the Fourier coefficients *should* be real and even (I am referring to a complex Fourier series). What am I missing to explain this discrepancy?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Fixed; however, the question still stands I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1/2$ is real so these coefficients are real.  (All the coefficients you didn't list are $0$, which is also real.)  Also, $a_n = a_{-n}$ for all $n$, so this set of coefficients has even symmetry.  There is no discrepancy, so I can't guess what you are missing.

Comment: Ah! I see my misunderstanding - I was interpreting $a_1$ and $a_{-1}$ as odd coefficients (as in -1 and 1 are odd integers). However, the correct interpretation of "odd harmonics" or "odd Fourier coefficients" (as you pointed out) is that when plotted in a graph, they show odd symmetry (about the origin). Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help.  (An example of odd symmetry is given by the sine function.)